# Modulo Congruence Prime Proofs

Tags: number-theory, logic, congruences, formal-proofs

Let p be an element of {2,3,4...}. Sppose that for all x,y (integers) if xy ≡ 0 mod p, then x ≡ 0 mod p or y ≡ 0 mod p. Show p is prime.

I did some work on this problem but I have gotten stuck.

---

(p|xy => ((p|x or p|y)) => P is prime

Take the contrapositive:

≡ !(P is Prime) => !(p|xy => ((p|x OR p|y) for all integers x,y)

≡ (P = ab) => !(! p|xy OR (p|x OR p|y) for all integers x,y))

```
a, b integers > 1
```

≡ (P = ab) => (p|xy AND !((p|x OR p|y) for all integers x,y)))

≡ (P = ab) => (p|xy AND ((!p|x AND !p|y for all integers x,y)))

P = ab represents composite numbers. We take x = a and y = b. We have ab|xy and ab does not divide x or y.

---

I dunno I thought I was getting somewhere with it, but I don't know if I went down the right path to prove it or not or where to go from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose to the contrary that $p\ge 2$ is composite (bigger than $1$ and not prime). Then there exist positive integers $x$ and $y$ such that $1\lt x\lt p$, $1\lt y\lt p$, and $xy=p$.  (Informally, $p$ has a non-trivial factorization,)

Thus $xy\equiv 0\pmod{p}$. But since $x$ and $y$ are positive and less than $p$, we have $x\not\equiv 0\pmod{p}$ and $y\not\equiv 0\pmod{p}$. This contradicts the condition that if $xy\equiv 0\pmod{p}$ then $x\equiv 0\pmod{p}$ or $y\equiv 0\pmod{p}$.

**Remark:** If the symbols cause trouble, note for example that $70=7\times 10$. Let $x=7$ and $y=10$. Then $xy\equiv 0\pmod{70}$, but $x\not\equiv 0\pmod{70}$ and $y\not\equiv 0\pmod{70}$. Precisely the same sort of thing can be done with any composite number.

Comment: So we assume the contrary (p is not prime), then show there's one case which shows that if p is composite the original congruency statements are false, this is enough to PROVE p must be prime? This shows P is prime because we assumed that P is not prime and "Sppose that for all x,y (integers) if xy ≡ 0 mod p, then x ≡ 0 mod p or y ≡ 0 mod p", and so the original statement says for all x,y this is true. However, we showed that if P is composite, then there is at least one combination of xy for which the other statements don't work, so we have a contradiction?

Comment: Er, that question got wordy, let me retry:                                                          So we assumed the contrary, that p is composite (not prime). Thus we have the original statement, and the assumption p is not prime. Since the original statement is that ALL x y will work for this, by showing there's at least one composite value of p that this statement does not hold true for, this produces a contradiction with p = composite, because if the statement was value with p = composite, we would not be able to find any example values of x y where the original statements fail to be tru?

Comment: Yes, if $p$ is composite then there is at least one pair $x$. $y$ for which the condition fails (actually there are infinitely many). But one is enough to get a contradiction from $p$ is composite. So $p$ cannot be composite.